# How to push particular key from array to other array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of "list"

```
let list = [
  {
  advance_amount: "100"
 id: "SUBMH9876"
  created_by: "12346"
  created_date: "Thu, 08 Nov 2018 11:23:00 GMT"

   },

    {
   advance_amount: "200"
   id: "SUBIH9876"
   created_by: "12346"
   created_date: "Thu, 08 Nov 2018 11:23:00 GMT"

    }
    ]
```

from the above array i want to push in another array like below format

```
 let subarray = [
             {id: "SUBMH9876"}, 
             {id: "SUBIH9876"}
             ]
```

I tried like below:

```
var subarray = list .map(function (el) { return el.id; });
```

But only values are showing in array

Comment: ok and what you tried?

Comment: var subarray = list .map(function (el) { return el.id; });

Comment: after using this i am getting only the values in array, But i am not getting with keys

Comment: Please edit and add your code snippet in the question

Comment: TRY LIKE `list.map(function (el) { return { id: el.id }; }); `

Comment: @downvoter, why this question get 5 down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let list = [{
    advance_amount: "100",
    id: "SUBMH9876",
    created_by: "12346",
    created_date: "Thu, 08 Nov 2018 11:23:00 GMT"

  },

  {
    advance_amount: "200",
    id: "SUBIH9876",
    created_by: "12346",
    created_date: "Thu, 08 Nov 2018 11:23:00 GMT"

  }
];

var subArr = list.map((item) => {
  return { id: item.id }
});

console.log(subArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do-

```
let list = [
  {
  advance_amount: "100",
   id: "SUBMH9876",
  created_by: "12346",
  created_date: "Thu, 08 Nov 2018 11:23:00 GMT"

   },

    {
   advance_amount: "200",
   id: "SUBIH9876",
   created_by: "12346",
   created_date: "Thu, 08 Nov 2018 11:23:00 GMT"

    }
    ]
    var list2=[];
   list.forEach((r)=>{
    list2.push({id:r.id});
    })
alert(list2)
```